# Facebook Feed Dialog URL Picture Param is not overwriting og:image

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share an infographic featured in an article, but the `&picture=` param in a facebook share url is being ignored and instead the image in the `og:image` meta tag is being shown. Need help ensuring that the facebook dialog box honors the picture parameter in the url.

I've tried using the Facebook Sharing Debugger, or a random image from another source but no difference.

My url structure is like the following:

In code:

```
const example = `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1234567890&display=popup&link=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&description=${encodeURIComponent(text)}&picture=https:${encodeURIComponent(img)}`
```

So I get something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1234567890&display=popup&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Farticle%2Fslug&description=Test%20Infographic%20Text%20Click%20the%20link%20to%20read%20more%20info!&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.example.net%2FexampleImage.jpg
```

I expect that when a user clicks on the Article share button that the image used in the dialog box is the same as in `og:image` but when I click on the share button on the infographic the image used in the dialog box is the same as in `&picture=` url param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom pictures are not possible anymore, you can only share with the `og:image` specified in the source.

Comment: Thanks I know that it's listed as deprecated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

Do you think they list it for the purposes of letting myself and others know that it won't work anymore? Or for people using older versions of their SDK?

Comment: they list it to tell people they cannot use them anymore. it does not really matter if it is for people using older versions of the sdk, even if it would work with older versions: new apps cannot use older versions anymore.